# Scale change on Quadratic

Tags: trigonometry, transformation, quadratics

Consider the two functions $f(x)=ax^2$ and $g(x)=bx^2$.
Using this transformation form $T(x,y)=(cx,cy)$,
find a scale change that maps $f(x)$ onto $g(x)$

Answer (score 2):

Temporarily, let $s=cx$ and $t=cy$. Then $x=\dfrac{s}{c}$ and $y=\dfrac{t}{c}$. Inserting in the equation $y=ax^2$ we get
$$\frac{t}{c}=a\frac{s^2}{c^2}.$$
We want this to read $t=bs^2$. For that, we need $\dfrac{a}{c}=b$, or equivalently $c=\dfrac{a}{b}$.

So now our equation reads $t=bs^2$. Replace the letter $s$ by $x$, and $t$ by $y$.

**Remark:** The result has an interesting geometric interpretation: all parabolas look alike, just like all circles look alike.